# Swift 4. No se refresca la vista luego de ejecutar la acción del UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift4

La alerta se muestra y al "presionar" el botón "OK!", las funciones `self.startNewRound()` y `self.updateLabels()` se ejecutan, pero los elementos de la vista (`self.targetLabel.text`, `self.scoreLabel.text`, `self.roundLabel.text`) no se actualizan, siguen apareciendo con los valores anteriores, hasta que toco en cualquier otro elemento, así no tenga código.

El siguiente es mi **ViewController**:

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var currentValueSlider : Int = 0
var initValueSlider : Int = 0
var targetValue : Int = 0
var score : Int = 0
var round : Int = 0

@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var targetLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var roundLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.initValueSlider = lroundf(slider.value)

    resetGame()
    updateLabels()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Movimiento del slider
@IBAction func sliderMove(_ sender: UISlider) {
    self.currentValueSlider = lroundf(sender.value)
}

//Validar el resultado
@IBAction func showAlert() {

    //_sender: UIButton

    //Valorar el resultado de la ronda del usuario
    let difference = abs(self.currentValueSlider - self.targetValue)

    //Puntuación
    var points = 100 - difference

    //Título del mensaje al usuario
    let tittle : String
    switch difference {
    case 0:
        tittle = "¡¡¡Puntuación perfecta!!!."
        points = points * 100
    case 1...5:
        tittle = "Casi perfecto!!."
        points = Int(Float(points) * 1.5)
    case 6...10:
        tittle = "Te ha faltado poco."
        points = Int(Float(points) * 1.2)
    default:
        tittle = "Sigue intentando."
    }
    self.score += points
    let message = "Has ganado \(points) puntos."

    let alert = UIAlertController (title: tittle, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let action = UIAlertAction (title: "Ok!", style: .default,
        handler:
        { action in
            self.startNewRound()
            self.updateLabels()
    })

    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func startNewGame(_ sender: UIButton) {
    resetGame()
    updateLabels()
}

func resetGame() {
    self.score = 0
    self.round = 0
    self.startNewRound()
}

//Calcular el número aleatorio
func startNewRound() {
    self.targetValue = 1 + Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    self.slider.value = Float(self.initValueSlider)
    self.round += 1

}

func updateLabels() {
    self.targetLabel.text = "\(self.targetValue)"
    self.scoreLabel.text = "\(self.score)"
    self.roundLabel.text = "\(self.round)"
}

}
```

---

Creo que el problema tiene que ver con el simulador en Xcode. Hice el deploy de la app en mi celular y funciona perfecto.

Comment: Eso suele ocurrir cuando se hace un llamado que actualiza el UI en un thread secundario (lo cual no se debe hacer), debes hacerlo en el thread principal. No veo donde se hace la llamada al ShowAlert, pero si estás haciendo una llamada a un servidor y en base a la respuesta llamando al showAlert, seguramente esa llamada a servidor es asincrona por lo que lo que  sus acciones igual.

Rogelio te muestra como se hace.

Adicionalmente, basando en el principio de responsabilidad unica, ShowAlert solo debería mostrar la alerta, no hacer todos los calculos.

Answer (score 0):

Por la descripción del problema, tal vez esté faltando llamar al método [`setNeedsDisplay()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622437-setneedsdisplay) de la vista:

```
let action = UIAlertAction (title: "Ok!", style: .default) { action in
    self.startNewRound()
    self.updateLabels()
    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: Creo que también funcionaría asi: `let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!", style: .default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in ....`

Answer (score 0):

Intenta llamando a las funciones de reload dentro del stack.

```
let action = UIAlertAction (title: "Ok!", style: .default,
    handler:
    { action in

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.startNewRound()
        self.updateLabels()
 }
})
```